# Extract images from HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to extract images from a HTML table and place them into a div. This is my JavaScript code:

```
var images = ""
var table = document.getElementById('table')
for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
        images += table.rows[i].cell[j].innerHTML
    }
    images += "<br>"
}
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = images
```

The issue is that it won't do anything to the div

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes the HTML this is working on, so that we can see what's happening and be able to help

Comment: Please add the corresponding HTML too

Comment: Just use a selector and get the images as elements (objects), not serialised as HTML: `let images = document.querySelectorAll('#table img')`, then loop over the collection using `images.forEach(img => document.querySelector('#div').appendChild(img)` will move all the images from the table to the div. If you want to copy the images across, just append a clone: `…append(img.cloneNode())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
var images = ""
var table = document.getElementById('table')
// I would change a bit how did you retrieve the rows, so instead of
// for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
// I would use
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
  // The same with the cols getting. Instead of 
  // for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
  // I would use the following
  for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
    images += col.innerHTML
  }
  images += "<br>"
}

// Let's check the result HTML string
console.log(images);

document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = images;
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://picsum.photos/201/300"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://picsum.photos/202/300"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="div"></div>
```

Codepen demo - https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/dyMRWGR?editors=1111

Comment: This looks like the start of a good answer, but it needs some explanation. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and what the changes you made do to fix the problem, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Thanks for your advice. I have added a few comments to the code to explain my point.

Comment: Thanks for updating, but it still doesn't explain how these changes fix the problem.  For example, can you explain what adding `row` into the `if` statement does? Letting users know how it works means that they understand what it is doing and will be able to change it if they need to, or even use it again in the future. And it is more likely to get upvotes over time as other users come to the site and find your explanation useful too. :)